# TSQL. Get Bitwise total for many columns in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

I have a table that has 4 sets of 25 columns in a BIT concept. Actually field is smallint but it is either 0 or 1 in it's data.

Here is my code that is an attempt to get the total for the first group of 25 cols.

```
Declare @rows int
, @ID uniqueidentifier
, @LocTotal bigint


select @rows =  ( select  count(*) from #t1 )

while @rows > 0
begin
print @rows
-- get that rowID
       select @ID = (select top 1 recid from #t1)
select @LocTotal =
(select top 1
case when cbHPILoc1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end +
case when cbHPILoc2 =  1 then 2 else 0 end +
case when cbHPILoc3 = 1 then  4 else 0 end +
< snip >
case when cbHPILoc25 = 1 then 16777216 else 0 end
as Total
 from  dbo.MyTest_BitMap
where RecKey = @ID
)
       print @ID
print  @LocTotal
```

My output:

```
(5 row(s) affected)
5
67A16306-B27D-4882-88A2-1146CBAAA8D9

(1 row(s) affected)
4
F94929B9-3DA7-4AA3-96F6-728EF025B21C
```

I fail to get the Total to `@LocTotal`

TIA

Comment: The code is not complete, so a lot of it doesn't really make sense... Do you actually have any records in MyTest_BitMap where RecKey matches the recid in #t1?

Comment: This is my first 5 columns cbHPILocN of the 25 total 
0 0 1 0 0

So I would expect @TotLoc >= 4  

But I get no amount back?

Comment: @__Stephen: What are you trying to do? Find out the bitmap for a given RecKey? Is there more than one row with a given RecKey? Are you trying to find *that* sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Tomalak has it, which is why I modded him up, but if you do this more or once, since all that mess:

```
cbHPILoc1
  + cbHPILoc2 * 2
  + cbHPILoc3 * 4
  + ...
  + cbHPILoc25 * 16777216
```

is tedious and error prone, why not do it once as a view and test that thoroughly?

Then just `select total from viewname where reckey = ?`.

Answer (score 3):

Why so complicated?

```
SELECT
  RecKey,
  cbHPILoc1
  + cbHPILoc2 * 2
  + cbHPILoc3 * 4
  + ...
  + cbHPILoc25 * 16777216
  AS Total
FROM
  dbo.MyTest_BitMap
WHERE 
  RecKey = @ID
```